# Slow mail sending from Excel, fast when attaching manually

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel

I have recently issues with email sending directly from Excel (save & send function). It quickly attaches mail to outlook window but when I press 'Send' button I have to wait 30-60 seconds

If I do that other way from Outlook (new mail, attach file) I dont need to wait

Any idea how to fix that it is quite annoying .. :(

Answer (score 0):

Is the attachment too big? What version of Outlook and Excel are you using? How about doing an upgrade?
Though Excel has a built-in feature called Send as Attachment and it’s a quick way to attach the file to an email, but I don't recommend using it. Reasons are shown in this article. https://www.excelcampus.com/keyboard-shortcuts/ways-to-attach-excel-files-to-emails/

Comment: Office 2010 problem occurs no matter what file size I have

Answer (score 0):

Does this only occur to Excel? Have you tried sending email from Word?

I'd like to recommend you repair Office to test the result.  To do this, please go to Control Panel > Programs and Features. Right click your Office suit and then choose Change. Click Repair.